# Is there a specification for bash?

Tags: bash

like other languages?

I googled it and came up with

https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=bash+specification

which did not list any specifications, just manuals and guides.

Thanks,

Comment: How is it off-topic to ask for the specification of a programming language?

Answer (score 7):

IEEE 1003.1 (“POSIX”) defines a standard “Shell Command Language”. [You can find the 2016 edition here.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html)

GNU Bash is an implementation of that language, with many extensions. The only specifications for the extended bash language are the [bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/) and the [bash source code](http://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=bash).

Answer (score 1):

I would consider the manual to be the spec. [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/)